# Call method if return value is not used

Tags: javascript, function, return

Here is a sample code that I want to achieve

```
function myObj(){
    this.method1 = function() { 
        console.log('method 1 is called'); 
    }
    // if method1 is not called ...
    this.default = function() { 
        console.log('default method is called'); 
    }
    return this;
}

myObj(); // call default
myObj().method1(); // call method1
```

In this code I want to be able to detect if the `myObj()` return object (which has a `method1` method) is being used or not.
If that's the case (if we chain `myObj()` to something else) then execute the last chained method. If not then execute a default method in `myObj()`;

One approach that I had was to return a function from `myObj()` and act like :

```
myObj()();
myObj().method1()();
```

I can also pass the method(s) to the base function and chain it inside the object :

```
myObj();
myObj(method1);
```

But maybe there is another way to do such thing, do you have an idea ?
Thanks,

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, can you give a real-world example?

Comment: Yes, working on it :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : that's what I thought but I wanted to be sure there was no other way to achieve this, still working on a example to illustrate...

Comment: If you leave off `this.default = function() {}` and stuff it inside the object itself, wouldn't it work as described? As in, `myObj()` would be _ran_ and `myObj.method1` would just be _defined_ but not _executed_. So `myObj()` and `myObj.method()` would do different things

Comment: @somethinghere : I don't quite understand what you said : The idea is to execute `myObj.default()` if nothing else is called right away...

Comment: @Nobe4 I missed out a little bit, but the answer by T.J. Crowder below essentially does what I meant, except it returns another object inside it, which I forgot.

Comment: Also note that if you want to instantiate a new object and that function acts as a constructor, you should use `new` operator, otherwise `this` points to the global object (in this case `window` object)

Comment: you're totally right, for the example it was simpler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't detect it within `myObj` without doing something like your example where you call the result, like this:

```js
function myObj(){
  var rv = function() {
    snippet.log("default method called");
  };
  rv.method1 = function() { 
    snippet.log('method 1 is called'); 
  };
  return rv;
}

myObj()();         // call default, note the extra ()
myObj().method1(); // call method1 [*no* extra ()]
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

In a comment I said requiring the extra `()` was asking for trouble because it would be so easy to forget, but of course, if `myObj` itself doesn't do anything but return a function, then if you forget the `()` you won't see the default functionality and presumably will realize you've forgotten the `()`.

---

In a comment elsewhere you said you might want to do chaining. You can do that with the above, just add "return rv" to the end of the functions:

```js
function myObj(){
  var rv = function() {
    snippet.log("default method called");
    return rv;
  };
  rv.method1 = function() { 
    snippet.log('method 1 is called'); 
    return rv;
  };
  return rv;
}

myObj()();             // call default, note the extra ()
myObj().method1();     // call method1 [*no* extra ()]
myObj()().method1()(); // call default, then method1, then default
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

I'm sure you've already ruled this out, but just for completeness: The usual way to do this would be for the "default" to be explicit, e.g.:

```js
function myObj(){
  return {
    _: function() {
      snippet.log("default method called");
    },
    method1: function() { 
      snippet.log('method 1 is called'); 
    }
  };
}

myObj()._();       // call default
myObj().method1(); // call method1
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

And then of course you can use the prototype chain and all the other standard object goodness.

Comment: OK, I like your solution but for consistency I think with extra `()` each time will be better, but yes the idea was to return a function that will be self invoked if not immediately used... I can try with a timeout but I don't think that will be good ...

Comment: @Nobe4: I thought of a timeout too, but I don't think that'll work. FWIW re consistency: I think it's consistent as above: There's always a second call in the expression, it's just if you want the default, you don't give a function name first. :-)

Comment: indeed, for the fun of it I will try to do it with a timeout, but yes your solution suits what I need. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Nobe4: You mentioned chaining elsewhere; I've added an example of that above.

Comment: your last example is neat :D

Answer (score 1):

Detecting if the return value of a function has its methods called later is not something that you can reasonably do. However, your plan of just passing the second function into the first is a tried-and-true pattern. You could do something like this:

```
function myObj(callback) {

    function defaultFunc() {/* code */}

    //other code, properties, etc

    //check if the user wants to chain functions
    if(callback) {
        callback();
    }
    //call the default function if there is nothing else to execute
    else {
        defaultFunc();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
myObj(method1); // Where method1 is a function defined somewhere
```

If you don't want to pass a whole function into your object but only want to execute one of myObj's properties, you could just pass the name of the function too.

```
function myObj(methodName) {

    this.defaultFunc = function() {/* code */}
    this.myMethod = function() {/* code */}

    //other code, properties, etc

    //check if the user wants to chain functions
    if(methodName && this[methodName]) {
        this[methodName]();
    }
    //call the default function if there is nothing else to execute
    else {
        this.defaultFunc();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
new myObj("method1"); // Note it's a string
```

Comment: yes that was one of my ideas, and i think that will be my final solution, because (I think) this way I can chain multiple methods easily. Thanks for the example :)

Comment: @Nobe4: You can indeed chain with the above (and also with my example of your other approach -- just add "return rv" to the functions).

Comment: `@Will` The code as written requires using the `new` operator (or calling the function in a fairly convoluted way). Not sure that's going to be workable for what @Nobe4 wants.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thats a good point. The first example doesn't really need it so I've edited it. Though it can't be avoided in the second example, and depending on the use case, it might be worth instantiating it.

Comment: @WillReese: You can avoid it in the second example as well, just create an object within the function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Like a map for function names to functions?

Comment: @WillReese: Exactly like you're using `this` for, but with `var rv = {};` to start with.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be helpful:

```
   var myObj = function(callDefault){
       if(callDefault){
           // DEFAULT METHOD GOES HERE
           console.log('default method is called')
           // DO SOMETHING
       }
       return {
           method1: function(){
               console.log('method 1 is called');
               // DO SOMETHING
           },
           method2: function(){
               console.log('method 2 is called');
               // DO SOMETHING
           }
       }
    }
```

`myObj(true)` // calls default function and returns list of other functions

`myObj().method1()` // Calls Method 1 Only

`myObj().method2()` // Calls Method 2 Only

`myObj(true).method1()` // Calls Default then Method 1

`myObj(true).method2()` // Calls Default then Method 2

Comment: I really like this one, actually. Its less cumbersome then returning a new object. Just wondering, though, doesnt this log 'default method ... called' when calling `myObj().method2()` as well?

Comment: yes, but the idea is not to execute the default if `method1` or `method2` is not called right away...

Comment: @Nobe4 actually, I just realised that. Woops.

Comment: @Nobe4 Just wondering if this solution would would if you just passed it something. Oh wait, the poster actually just amended it in that way. I would invert the boolean though, simply because `myObj(false)` reads more like it doesnt get called.

Comment: I've updated it to not call default when donotcalldefault parameter is assiged

Comment: you're right, but if I am to pass arguments to `myObj` I prefere to pass it  a list of methods to chain...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the example,  this is not the way to do :

```
function myObj(){
    var isCalled = false;
    this.method1 = function() { 
        isCalled = true;
        console.log('method 1 is called'); 
    }
    this.default = function() { 
        if(isCalled) return;
        console.log('default method is called'); 
    }
    setTimeout(this.default, 1000); // default time
    return this;
}

myObj(); // after 1 s default is called
myObj().method1(); // method1 is called right away and default is never called
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need a constructor function that takes one argument as input and creates an object with a method attached to it. If the input argument was a valid call-back function then call it, otherwise call a default function instead.

```
function myObj(callback) {
    this.method = function() {
        if(typeof callback == 'function'){
            callback();
            console.log('call-back is called');                 
        } else {
            // default function
            console.log('default method is called'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
(new myObj()).method();             // call default
(new myObj(somefunction)).method(); // call 'somefunction'
```

Comment: yes, but the idea was to achieve this without any `()` or parameters more, but it turns out that's not possible, ...